# the argument type 'widget' can't be assegned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

the argument type 'widget' can't be assegned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

```
class home_screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const home_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: myAppBar(),
    );
  }
}

Widget myAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    elevation: 0,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AppBar` implements `PreferredSizeWidget` and `Scaffold` expect the `appBar` property to be of type `PreferredSizeWidget`

Simply do:

```
PreferredSizeWidget myAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    elevation: 0,
  );
}
```

Comment: Your text is a little misleading, an AppBar *is* indeed a Widget.

Comment: Oh, thanks @nvoigt...I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the `AppBar` is a Widget, the `Scaffold` needs a `PreferredSizeWidget` to work. Well, an `AppBar` does implement `PreferredSizeWidget`, but your method hides that fact. Since you *know* it's an AppBar, there is no point in generalizing it, just make your function return that type:

```
AppBar myAppBar() { 
  return AppBar( 
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    elevation: 0,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your myAppBar function type then it will work.

```
PreferredSizeWidget myAppBar() {
        return AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          elevation: 0,
        );
      }
```